# WooCommerce update a product when opening single product view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to update my product with data that comes from an API query. I would like to update the products data when visiting the single products view. I'm new to WordPress and WooCommerce, but I think this can be done through hooks?

I've tried looking for hooks but haven't had any luck yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the example below.

This will run every time the product is viewed. Of course, you have to add your own API call and adapt the function to your data structure.

```
    add_action('wp', 'update_product_data');
     function update_product_data(){
     if (class_exists('WooCommerce') && is_product()) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        // Call the external API to get the updated product data
        $api_url = 'http://example.com/api/product/' . $product_id;
        $response = wp_remote_get($api_url);

        // Check for successful response and decode the JSON data
        if (!is_wp_error($response) && wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response) == 200) {
                $data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

            // Update the product's weight and description with the data from the API
            $product->set_weight($data['weight']);
            $product->set_description($data['description']);
            $product->save();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I exactly go about updating the products data using one of these hooks?

Comment: Well, you have to be more specific, what data you want to update? And how often? These hooks will run every time when the product is viewed. It's a big difference if you want to update the price of the product or if you want to change the description of the product, title or something else.

Comment: I would like to update the weight and description

Comment: Also, I need to actually update the product not just change what gets displayed

Comment: In that case, the frontend migth not be the best place to make this update. What are you really trying to do here? Who is updating the weight and description? What are the values? Why don't you update them in the admin pages? Please add more details if you expect a correct answer.

Comment: I have data coming from an API. I would like to update the specific products data with data from the API every time someone visits the single product view. I'm not in control of the API